# Securing requesting info POST

Tags: php, android

I have some Volley request so the user gets their info, but i want to make the request secure like some API Key, but I have no idea how to do it. Can I get some advice please, Thanks in advance. Below u can see how i request & retrieve the info.

want something like that I send API Key with the Volley parameter, and server-side i check if the Key matches with server
[PHP]

```
            case 'userData':
                if(isTheseParametersAvailable(array('email'))){
                    
                    $email = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);


                    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT points, likes, views FROM users WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1");
                    $stmt->bind_param("s",$email);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->store_result();


                        $stmt->bind_result($points, $likes, $views;
                        $stmt->fetch();

                        $array = array(array(
                            "points" => $points, 
                            "likes" => $likes,
                            "views" => $views
                        ));

                    echo json_encode($array);
                }

            break;
```

[Java]

```
public void userData() {
        final String email = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getUserEmail();
        String uRl = URLs.URL_USER_DATA;
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, uRl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response){
                try{
                    JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(response);
                    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            SharedPrefManager.setMyPoints(jsonObject.getString("points"));
                            SharedPrefManager.setMyLikes(jsonObject.getString("likes"));
                            SharedPrefManager.setMyViews(jsonObject.getString("views"));

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }catch (JSONException e2){
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                return;
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> param = new HashMap<>();
                param.put("email", email);
                return param;
            }
        };
        request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(30000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        MySingleton.getmInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(request);
    }
```

Comment: are you validating user on their email ids, because your only parameter in sql is email, which hardly anyone provides correct

Comment: @aryanagarwal Hey sorry for late reply, Yes i am validating every requests with email, do you think that's enough or should i try to apply some API key as a second validation?

Comment: No I am saying are you verifying user mail id , by sending them link on their mail and then verifying

Comment: @aryanagarwal oh no, when the user opens the app, the userData() will be executed, and it will send POST request, and the response I get with the info is the email I give with the userData parameter.

Comment: so if I create account with someone else mail id will it execute then as well

Comment: @aryanagarwal you cannot make another account if the email already exist in the DB

Comment: but you can create account by providing my friends email id

Comment: yes, but then it will grab the info of your friends email adress, and not someone elses.

Comment: but this is not good try to verify if the person is the actual owner of that mail account

Comment: When you login to the app with your email adress, it does save the email in Sharedpreferences, and when the userData() is executed it gets the email from Sharedpreferences. So there is no way that you can get the info of someone elses email adress.

Comment: and what if I create account using person A mail id and then person A also decides to use your app and sees that mailid is already occupied, so will you let me create account with person A mail id

Comment: No, the person A will not be able to create account with that emailId. That person A should use now a different email.